# dbinom - 4 parameter logistic regression

Tags: r, function, logistic-regression

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(broom)
library(BiodiversityR)
library("vegan")#[1]
library("MASS")#[2]
library(nlme)#[3]
library("bbmle")
```

Here are the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e_XOgTv1flSFFleHSwUJJPBzBdd9VPXRaZc2oukwtrE/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm assessing which model best suit my data (null model/glm-poisson/4 parameter log). The idea of using log is to detect at which point the response (number, proportion of species) decreases/increases at certain values of forest cover in the landscape. I've been using the next code to fit a four parameter logistic regression using dpois (y=count of species):

```
logip=function(p,lambda,x){
  a=p[1]
  b=p[2]
  c=p[3]
  d=p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST700+km))/c)))
  -sum(dpois(x,lambda=Riq1, log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=2,b=60,c=3,d=0.1),
               data=list(x=Patch_Richness))
```

But now I want to use the same approach for dependent variable that is a proportion (y=proportion of species registered in one site). I think I should be using binomial, so I'm trying `dbinom` in my previous function:

```
logip=function(p,size,prob){
 a=p[1]
 b=p[2]
 c=p[3]
 d=p[4]
 Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST500+km))/c)))
 -sum(dbinom(size,prob=Riq1))
}parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=1,b=72,c=3,d=0.1),
               data=list(x=cbind(Regional_Richness,Patch_Richness)))
```

I'm getting this message:

> Error in mle2(minuslog = logip, start = c(a = 1, b = 72, c = 3, d = 0.1), : some named arguments in 'start' are not arguments to the specified log-likelihood function.

I don´t know if it is correct to use `dbinom` and how to apply this in the function I'm using. Hope you can help me.

Comment: For starters you wouldn't use a logistic regression to model Poisson count data. Logistic regression models binary dependent variables that take values 0 or 1, whereas Poisson distributed variables can take on any non-negative integer value. It would be helpful if you could include some of your data, what you're trying to accomplish, and what packages you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I've included a link and packages I'm using

Comment: is there a typo in the second function; you use  `dnorm` instead of `dbinom`

Comment: yes, there was a typo, it is correct now

Comment: Google sheets is asking me to ask for access. Can you make the data freely downloadable?

Comment: thanks Ben, I've changed access - it is free now

Answer (score 1):

For the binomial distribution, there are two parameters. It looks like the Patch_Richness is never greater than 2, so I set the size parameter to 2, and used your formula to predict the probability parameter. Notice the log likelihood is -23.

```
library(bbmle)
text="Bioma_MAPBIOMAS   km  Regional_Richness   Patch_Richness  Richness_prop   FOREST500
Cerrado 35.1    2   2   1   100
Cerrado 131.4   2   2   1   100
Cerrado 40  2   1   0.5 100
Cerrado 8   1   1   1   72.37
Cerrado 28  1   0   0   85.06
Cerrado 5   1   0   0   29.65
Cerrado 5   1   0   0   25.38
Cerrado 28  1   0   0   77.97
Cerrado 5   1   0   0   70.09
Cerrado 28  1   0   0   100
Cerrado 20  1   0   0   97.48
Cerrado 8   1   0   0   66.89
Cerrado 8   1   0   0   77.96
Cerrado 8   1   0   0   65.17
Cerrado 8   1   0   0   50.86
Cerrado 20  1   0   0   89.1
Cerrado 3   1   1   1   31.49
Cerrado 27.8    1   1   1   62.9"
df=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
logip=function(p,x){
  a=p[[1]]
  b=p[[2]]
  c=p[[3]]
  d=p[[4]]
  Riq1 = d+a/(1+exp((b-(x$FOREST500+x$km))/c))
  if (any(Riq1>=1) | any(Riq1<=0)) {
    return(9999999)
  }
  -sum(log(dbinom(x$Patch_Richness, 2, prob=exp(Riq1)/(1+exp(Riq1)))))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=.1,b=72,c=1,d=.1),
               data=list(x=df))
Call:
mle2(minuslogl = logip, start = c(a = 0.1, b = 72, c = 1, d = 0.1), 
    data = list(x = df))

Coefficients:
           a            b            c            d 
3.811005e-02 7.200033e+01 1.000584e+00 8.823313e-04 

Log-likelihood: -22.45
```

Here is the same thing for the poisson distribution. Note the log likelihood is -14. Thus, the poisson distribution is better given your equation `Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(x$FOREST500+x$km))/c)))` and initial conditions.

```
logip=function(p,x){
  a=p[[1]]
  b=p[[2]]
  c=p[[3]]
  d=p[[4]]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(x$FOREST500+x$km))/c)))
  if (any(Riq1<=0)) {
    return(9999999)
  }
  -sum(dpois(x$Patch_Richness,lambda=Riq1, log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=2,b=60,c=3,d=0.1),
               data=list(x=df))
modTR.log

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = logip, start = c(a = 2, b = 60, c = 3, d = 0.1), 
    data = list(x = df))

Coefficients:
          a           b           c           d 
 0.49350452 77.68600468  0.04856004  0.14285921 

Log-likelihood: -14.5
```

Comment: Thx!. Ran this for y=Richness_prop: 
  `-sum(log(dbinom(x$Richness_prop, 1, prob=exp(Riq1)/(1+exp(Riq1)))))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")
modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=1,b=72,c=1,d=0),
               data=list(x=df))'`                                                                                             
  Got:`Error in optim(par = c(a = 1, b = 72, c = 1, d = 0), fn = function (p)  : 
  non-finite finite-diff value 
In dbinom(x$Richness_prop, 1, prob = exp(Riq1)/(1 + exp(Riq1))) :
  non-integer x = 0.5`

Comment: Also tried this: `}
  -sum(log(dbinom(x$cbind(Regional_Richness,Patch_Richness), 1, prob=exp(Riq1)/(1+exp(Riq1)))))
}`...... here I tried to include Richness proportion as in glm, but did not work either:` Error in x$cbind(Regional_Richness, Patch_Richness) : 
  attempt to apply non-function `

Comment: @mmr09 It could be because there is a value of 0.5 in the Richness_prop column but binomial of size 2 only predicts 0,1,2 (no fractions). You can do it using Regional_Richness, because that column contains only 1's and 2's.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what should I use for Richness_proportion? I really need to use this as y, and have other data sets with values of 0.5, 0.67, 0.43...etc. I thought binomial was appropriate for such kind of data, which in my case is Patch_richness/Regional/Richness

Comment: Try something like glm(data=df, Richness_prop ~ FOREST500 + km, family=“binomial”) @mmr09 maybe you’re referring to this binomial family instead of the binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this: glm(data=df, Richness_prop ~ FOREST500 + km, family=“binomial”), which is fine. But I want to use the 4 parameter log regresion to compare with glm. Still don´t get it